# Execute function when 2 conditions are verified: ajax response and timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, request

I'm trying to simulate something like this:

- a click on a button displays a modal popup saying 'loading stuff', with an overlay
- in the meantime i perform an ajax call with jQuery and let a timer of 2 seconds start
- i need to hide the modal popup once i get a response from the ajax call ***and*** my timer ends.

My ajax request may return in less than 2 seconds but i need the user to read the message in the popup, and may returns after 2 seconds (but i need it to return to proceed).

I tried to investigate $.when but i cannot find a way to set the 'timer' part properly.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're set on using `$.when`, you can create a Deferred which resolves after `x` milliseconds;

```
function timedDeferred(n) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function () {
        deferred.resolve();
    }, n);

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

... and you could then use `$.when`;

```
$.when($.ajax(), timedDeferred(2000)).then(function (ajax) {
    // "ajax" is an array of the arguments that $.ajax() provides; see
    // the bottom of http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/
});
```

Comment: Wonderful, working like a charm! Thanks for being so quick/clear/simple